# facing error of react-codegen and build failed

Tags: xcode, react-native, codegen

Facing build error, using below versions

```
Xcode: 14.3.1
react-native: "0.70.6",
ruby 2.7.5p203
Node: 20.3.1

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBnnN.png
```